# How can I use Footnotes with Oracle BI Publisher

Tags: ms-word, report, bi-publisher, infobip

I am putting a footnote in an `.rtf` template, and before generating a report it seems ok,
but when I load an `XML` sample and preview the document (`.pdf` or `.doc` etc.)
the **footnote** content **goes** right **into the body** of my report (example is in the *picture*).

- I've tried using *text boxes*, but it doesn't help.
- I've also tried just making a paragraph look as a footnote, but since I have a lot of
  tags in my template, the footnote-looking text doesn't stay at the
  bottom of the page.
- and I can't use footers/headers because **I need only one footnote at one page**.

[image: template vs report example]

Comment: Is the footnote required on first page or other specific page?

Answer (score 0):

Try to draw a borderless table with one column and two rows where the first row has fixed hight (exactly) of the size of body, and the second row fixed hight of the size you want to reserve for the footer. Then you place your xml data in those two rows of the table the same way as you put it on the page. I use that for different forms when the position of the data is fixed. There are also other table/row/column properties that you might want to use.